# Trying to call one method on multiple buttons but only one button uses the method

Tags: java, button, methods

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Pepsi");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            changeD();
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(23, 11, 80, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Sprite");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            changeD();
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(113, 11, 80, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);
    JButton btnFanta = new JButton("Fanta");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            changeD();
        }

    });
```

these are the buttons calling the method.This is where i have a problem, only one button click works, the pepsi button

This next part is the methood I am calling. It determines if the coins and amount entered are correct.

```
public double changeD() {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This Product costs 1.50 EU");
        String payment = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please insert cash");
        int intAmount = Integer.parseInt(payment); 
        double drinkPrice = 1.50;
        double changeDue = intAmount - drinkPrice;
        if (intAmount == 2 + 1 + .50 && intAmount > drinkPrice) 

        {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please take your product and change " + changeDue);

        }

        else if (intAmount != 2 + 1 + .50 || intAmount < drinkPrice)

        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please insert correct amount or coins ");
        }

         return (Double) null;
```

Comment: Try `btnNewButton_1.addActionListener` and `btnFanta.addActionListener`. You keep on adding action listeners to the same button.

Comment: What are you suggesting I change?

Comment: sorry i couldnt see whole comment, thanks andy i will change it now :)

Comment: You're a goddamn genius Andy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice you have a mistake probably do to copy pasting you set the same button with ActionListener twice

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Pepsi");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        changeD();
    }
});
btnNewButton.setBounds(23, 11, 80, 29);
contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Sprite");

//Wrong button here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Should be btnNewButton_1 
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        changeD();
    }
});
btnNewButton_1.setBounds(113, 11, 80, 29);
contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);
JButton btnFanta = new JButton("Fanta");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        changeD();
    }

});
```

Comment: Please explain the problem and solution, don't just dump code. Aside from anything else, you've left an instance of the problem in your "answer".

Comment: My problem is that I have overlooked that i was referencing the same button everywhere. The program executes the method when clicking any of the buttons. Now I just need to offer the option of canceling the purchase in the method